# How to access an object within object?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, stack

I am trying to build a blackjack game. I have created a deck, now I want to display it.

I know I'm doing something wrong because I cannot access displayStack within CardStack class.  Also, I have a feeling that I'm not doing inheritance correctly.  How could I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
public class CreateCardDeck {
    int deckSize = 52;
    CardStack cardStack = new CardStack(deckSize);

    public void CreateDeck() {
        String[] suit = {"clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"};
        int[] rank = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

        for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i ++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++) {
                cardStack.push(suit[j], rank[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Card class:

```
class Card {
    String suit;
    int rank;

    Card(String suit, int rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public String getRank() {
        String nameTheRank;
        if (rank == 1)
            nameTheRank = "Ace";
        else if (rank == 11)
            nameTheRank = "Jack";
        else if (rank == 12)
            nameTheRank = "Queen";
        else if (rank == 13)
            nameTheRank = "King";
        else
            nameTheRank = String.valueOf(rank);
        return nameTheRank;
    }
}
```

CardStack class:

```
class CardStack {
    public void displayDeck() {
        for (int i = 0; i < stackArray.length; i ++)
            System.out.println(stackArray[i]);
    }
}
```

The Main Class:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CreateCardDeck c = new CreateCardDeck();
        c.CreateDeck();
        // How to display my deck?
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `CardStack` class? Is it `Card` class you are talking about? And I can't see any Inheritance here. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: @Rohit Jain,  yes, I'd like to access CardStack's displayDeck from the MainClass.

Comment: Yeah sure, but where is that class? `displayDeck` is in `Card class`.

Comment: @Rohit Jain, You'r right, I've posted too little code. Sorry. There's an additional class out there.

Comment: Please follow the advice in @JonSkeet's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redesign your types to start with. `CreateCardDeck` sounds like it should really be a static method called `createDeck` within a `CardDeck` or possibly just `Card` type. It also sounds like the knowledge of suits and number shouldn't really be part of that method. Cards are often used as a demonstration of enums in Java - one enum for the values (ace to king) and one for the suits.

Think about what it really means to have an *instance* of `CreateCardDeck` - does that really make sense to you? It feels more like a verb (a method) than a noun (a type).

Now you *could* have a `CardDeckFactory` or something similar - but then I wouldn't expect the deck to be part of the state of the object; it would just be returned by a method.

Comment: If it will make a big of a difference, please reread my post. :)

Comment: Just one small comment, I haven't done any statics this semester so probably I should avoid it. Although I try to make sense of your post I like your understanding of how to implement methods and types. Clever :)

Comment: @HelpNeeder: Well, you could have a `CardDeckFactory` with an instance method to return a new deck then.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this ie. extend class `CreateCardDeck` and refer it's `cardStack` variable?

```
 class Card extends CreateCardDeck
 {
    public void displayDeck()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cardStack.size(); i ++)
            System.out.println(cardStack.get(i));
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's be simple as possible : you need a card to begin to play cards, it's better.
Then you need a Deck to stock all your card.

So you can just have two classes : Deck and Card. When you create an instance of a deck, it generates the 52 cards you need to play.

```
public class Card{}

public class Deck
{
    int deckSize = 52;
    // Here you certainly need a list or a stack to stock your card
    SomeContainer cardStack;

    public Deck()
    {
        String[] suit = {"clubs", "diamonds", "hearts", "spades"};
        int[] rank = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

        for (int i = 0; i < rank.length; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < suit.length; j++)
            {
                cardStack.push(new Card(suit[j], rank[i]));
            }
        }
    }

    public void Display()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cardStack.length; i ++)
            System.out.println(cardStack[i]);
    }
}

public class MainClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        deck.Display();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you did not display your CardStack class, and did not display all of the Card class

basically you should have a showCards() method in it ,
and also in the card itself it would be useful to implement toString that represent the card:
something like this:

suppose you have a list or array of cards :

```
public void showCards() {
   for (Card card : cards) {
       System.out.println(card);
   }
}
```

and in the Card:

```
public class Card {

   private String suit;
   private int rank;

   public String toString() {
       return rank + " of " + suit;
   }

   //...the rest of the code   
}
```

in CreateCardDeck add a getter:

```
public CardSTack getCardStack() {
    return cardStack; 
}
```

and then in your main just add:

```
c.getCardStack().showCards();
```